# Jooq codegen classes for ref-cursor on oracle12 and oracle19

Tags: java, oracle, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I have plsql code in package context:

```
type t_demand_for_excel_upload is record
(
    bsns_oper_name t_string,
    demand_date date,
    demand_hour integer,
    demand_value number
);
type t_cur_demands_for_excel_upload is ref cursor return t_demand_for_excel_upload;

procedure get_demands_for_excel_upload
(
    p_calc_version_id in integer,
    p_shop_id in integer,
    p_start_date in date,
    p_end_date in date,
    p_result out t_cur_demands_for_excel_upload
);
```

Jooq version:

```
<jooq.groupId>org.jooq.pro</jooq.groupId>
<jooq.version>3.12.3</jooq.version>
<jooq.generator.db.dialect>org.jooq.meta.oracle.OracleDatabase</jooq.generator.db.dialect>
```

When i generate code using oracle 12c - thats ok, it looks like this in java:

```
public static Result<Record> getDemandsForExcelUpload(Configuration configuration, BigInteger pCalcVersionId, BigInteger pShopId, LocalDate pStartDate, LocalDate pEndDate) {
        GetDemandsForExcelUpload f = new GetDemandsForExcelUpload();
        f.setPCalcVersionId(pCalcVersionId);
        f.setPShopId(pShopId);
        f.setPStartDate(pStartDate);
        f.setPEndDate(pEndDate);

        f.execute(configuration);
        return f.getReturnValue();
    }
```

`Result<Record>` as I expected.

Debug in maven:
[image]

On oracle 19c generated code looks like this:

```
public static TDemandForExcelUploadRecord getDemandsForExcelUpload(Configuration configuration, BigInteger pCalcVersionId, BigInteger pShopId, LocalDate pStartDate, LocalDate pEndDate) {
        GetDemandsForExcelUpload f = new GetDemandsForExcelUpload();
        f.setPCalcVersionId(pCalcVersionId);
        f.setPShopId(pShopId);
        f.setPStartDate(pStartDate);
        f.setPEndDate(pEndDate);

        f.execute(configuration);
        return f.getReturnValue();
    }
public class TDemandForExcelUploadRecord extends UDTRecordImpl<TDemandForExcelUploadRecord> implements Record4<String, LocalDate, BigInteger, BigDecimal> { ...
```

Where is my cursor? Please help.

Maven  debug for oracle 19c:
[image]

The jooq settings are identical in both cases

Comment: That looks like a bug that might have been introduced with https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7861. I'll investigate this soon and revert with further information.

Comment: If i change return type t_cur_demands_for_excel_upload to sys_refcursor it work well.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense as a workaround

Comment: @LukasEder Any news?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in jOOQ 3.14, or rather a missing feature. We didn't have any integration tests for strongly typed `REF CURSOR` types, so we hadn't noticed this regression. I've created two issues for this:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11708 A feature request to add support for typed `REF CURSOR` types
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11709 A Bug to revert to the old behaviour until the feature request is implemented for 3.15.0 and 3.14.9. If you need the fix in an earlier patch release, please get in touch through the commercial support channels.